# Milkdrop 2 visualization with iTunes

Tags: itunes, winamp

Milkdrop 2 is the best visualizer program I've seen.  While iTunes has it's flaws, it's smart playlists are one of the more powerful ways to manage your music.

How can I play my music using iTunes but use Milkdrop 2 for the visualizations?

Milkdrop 2 is a plug-in for WinAmp so I have spent some time playing with the LineIn plugin which works ok but is not ideal because I actually have to use a microphone next to the speakers to get it to work.

I'd like something that directly makes the audio available to WinAmp on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MilkDrop page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MilkDrop), [projectM](https://github.com/projectM-visualizer/projectm/releases) is a port of Milkdrop using OpenGL.

It's available as a plugin for iTunes, Audacious, XMMS, Winamp, Jack, PulseAudio and foobar2000.

[image]